# How to solve these kind nonhomogeneous heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve 
>   $$\begin{cases}
> u_{t}-u_{xx}=\frac{1}{2}xt \ \ &\text{for} \ \ 0\lt x\lt \pi, t\gt0\\
> u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0  \ \    \\
> u(x,0) = \sin x   \ \ \\
> \end{cases}$$

How to transform it to the normal case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find a solution of the form

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_n T_n(t)X_n(x) $$

where

\begin{cases}
X'' = -\lambda^2 X \\
X(0) = X(\pi) = 0
\end{cases}

You'll get

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n(t)\sin(nx) $$

and the PDE becomes

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\big[T_n'(t) + n^2T_n(t)\big]\sin(nx) = \frac12 tx $$

Decompose the RHS into the corresponding Fourier series

$$ \frac12 tx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(t) \sin(nx) $$

You'll get a family of IVPs

\begin{cases} 
T_n''(t) + n^2 T_n(t) = a_n(t) \\
T_1(0) = 1 \\
T_{n>1}(0) = 0
\end{cases}

Comment: There is one thing  I'm confused, in fact we can get $X''=-\lambda^2 X$ in homogeneous case because $\frac{X''}{X}=\frac{T'}{T}$ has to be a constant. But in this nonhomogeneous case, I can only get $T'X=X''T+\frac{1}{2}xt$.

Comment: The full explanation is a bit complicated. This method isn't separation of variables, just related to it. It just so happens that the eigenfunctions in $x$ span the full  function space, so we use it as a basis of our solution. Think of it like an eigenvalue-eigenvector decomposition.

Comment: Okay, think I'll find it in my following study. Thanks a lot